# While loop not starting display at 5, starting with input, C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm having an issue with my while loop in my c++ program. It runs, but I am trying to get it to begin with 5 (needs to display numbers in increments of 5) instead of with my input number. Here is the loop:

```
    while (minutes <= 25) // max number displayed 25, minutes is my own input between 5 - 25
{
    caloriesBurn = minutes * burnperMin; // calculating calories burned
    if (minutes%5 == 0) // determining if number is divisible by 5
    {
        cout << minutes << "        " << caloriesBurn << endl; 
    }

    minutes++;
}
```

As of right now, if I input 15, it will display starting at 15 and go to 20 then 25 (like I want) but I always want it to start at 5, and run until my input (15). So, basically it is displaying the opposite of what I want.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? Do you not know how to set a variable to 5 and then increment it?

Comment: It would seem so, I'm just at a loss with the whole thing at this point

Comment: The *start* the loop at five (or zero or one or whatever) and count up to the input? *Think* a little bit about what you said in the question, and how to arrange a loop condition like you want. You actually spell out the correct loop condition in the text after the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int m = 5; m <= minutes; m += 5)
{
     caloriesBurn = m * burnperMin; // calculating calories burned
     cout << m << "        " << caloriesBurn << endl; 
}
```

Comment: You need to increment one at a time, unless you refactor the `caloriesBurn` calculation (which would become the sum of an AP with 5 terms).

Comment: Why do you say that? The results of the calculations that aren't displayed are ignored.

Comment: I say that since `caloriesBurn` is not scoped to the loop. Your solution changes its value.

Comment: So does the original. There was no indication that there was a problem, so I didn't change that behavior.

Comment: You're correct. For some reason I thought the OP was using +=. Plus one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use the while loop.

Comment: And you can't figure out how to turn that `for` loop into a `while` loop? If that's the case, you don't understand enough C to benefit from the answers you're going to get. You just need to learn basic C language control structures.

Comment: Just to add to the above -- you need to learn C control structures. There's no special reason why you should try to do it in the context of this particular task and it will just make that process harder. And once you understand them, you'll be able to answer this yourself. So you're making extra effort for yourself trying to understand answers to the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for (minutes = 5; minutes <= 25; minutes += 5)` instead, and remove `minutes++;` at the end of the loop body, along with the now-redundant divisibility check.

If you need to retain the `while` then refactor to the equivalent

```
minutes = 5;
while (minutes <= 25){
    /* loop body*/
    minutes += 5;
}
```

Comment: I have to use the while loop unfortunately, rubric says :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, as in you want the condition to be, (keeping your code as much as possible)

```
int minutes = 5;
while (minutes < 25 && minutes < userInput) {
    caloriesBurn = minutes * burnperMin; // calculating calories burned
    cout << minutes << "        " << caloriesBurn << endl;
    minutes += 5;
}
```

This is assuming you want it to display the calories burned at 5,10,... minutes up to a user-defined time with a maximum of 25 minutes.